# roslib.message.get_message_class returns None

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, service, rospy, roslib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create a tool that can dynamicly read service call descriptions from a yaml file and call the services accordingly. (in rospy on kinetic)

If i try to resolve a **non-standard** *service type* form a string, **roslib.message.get_message_class** returns **None**.
Why does this happen?
Shouldn't it either throw an error, like when the string doesn't mean anything, or return the correct type?

---

```
try:
  msg_type = roslib.message.get_message_class('somethingstupid')
  if msg_type is None:
    rospy.logwarn('msg_type is None')
except:
  rospy.logerr('roslib.message.get_message_class failed')
```

results in

> roslib.message.get_message_class
> failed

while

```
try:
  msg_type = roslib.message.get_message_class('my_package/MyMsgType')
  if msg_type is None:
    rospy.logwarn('msg_type is None')
except:
  rospy.logerr('roslib.message.get_message_class failed')
```

results in

> msg_type is None

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310607/roslib.message.get_message_class-returns-none/) by [G](https://answers.ros.org/users/30847/g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"get_service_class" would have been the solution.

sorry for the useless question

---

Originally posted by [G](https://answers.ros.org/users/30847/g/) with karma: 46 on 2018-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0